# Upgrade to 1.9.2.4 duplicating block in footer

Tags: magento-1.9, footer, custom-block, ce-1.9.2.4

I have created static blocks in CMS then added them to the footer of RWD theme and everything had been working great. I just upgraded files to 1.9.2.4 via Magento Connect Manager and now one block is being duplicated.

my partial `local.xml` for this looks like:

```
<reference name="footer">
<remove name="footer.newsletter" />
<remove name="footer_links" />
<remove name="footer_links2" />

<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_company" before="footer_links_quick">
<!--
    The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
    You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
-->
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_company</block_id></action>
    </block>
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_quick" after="footer_links_company">
<!--
    The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
    You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
-->
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_quick</block_id></action>
</block>
<block type="cms/block" name="cms_footer_links_account" after="footer_links_quick">
<!--
    The content of this block is taken from the database by its block_id.
    You can manage it in admin CMS -> Static Blocks
-->
<action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_links_account</block_id></action>
</block>   
<block type="cms/block" name="footer_social_links">
    <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>footer_social_links</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

It is the first block, `footer_links_company`, that is duplicating. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by just renaming the block via Admin -> CMS - static blocks, then updating the proper places in local.xml.